# TreePanel - How to disable URL modifications like "root?node=root"?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

`TreePanel`s in ExtJS 4 are adding weird parameters to the end of the specified URL in the `model`'s `proxy`. First parameter was something about caching that I was able to disable setting `noCache: false`.

The other parameter is also causing trouble, it is adding something in the format like `{id}?node={id}` to the end of the URL, as in `"GET /servers/root?node=root HTTP/1.1" 200 777`.

The URL is the address to a REST API, which in most of the cases it is OK to send these extra parameters, but in more complicated cases, this can't be handled, or it is too much specific case to be a reason to added to (or ignored by) the API's logic. And it's counter-MVC.

How can I disable this `root?node=root`-like parameter, as it have no use for me?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but I'd try interfering with the proxy's `params` before making the call. Each param is appended to the url so if you remove unwanted ones they won't be send. The exact point to do it depends on your implementation and you might need to override your proxy's load.

Comment: Alright, so I believe this is the right direction, _but_ the `TreeStore` have its proxy defined by the model that I specified in it, so how can I modify the proxy's `params`? In the model too? Because this is really specific of the `TreeStore`.

Comment: I haven't done this specifically in a tree store, but I remember once, tampering with it to remove some to match an api. It's been a while so I don't remember the details. I think you need to override the proxy (`buildUrl`?). Try looking at the Sencha forums. There are some custom proxies (search for ODATA) that did this and much more. It will give you some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your tree store is trying to get a new root everytime you expand a node.
Try changing your root to 'root >'
That will permanently set your root.